# Why does gcc optimise away this C++11 foreach loop using my custom iterator?

Tags: c++, c++11, foreach, iterator

I was trying to write some code for doing functional-style creation of sequences. I wrote one function, `range(a, b)`, which returns an object that you can iterate over, foreach-style, to go through the numbers a, a + 1, ..., b - 1. Then I wrote another function, `map(f, t)`, which returns another iterable object where each element in the sequence is the result of calling `f` with the corresponding element of the iterable object `t`.

This works as expected if I compile using `-O1` or lower; with `-O2` or higher, my foreach loop (in `main` at the bottom) gets completely optimised away and nothing is printed. Why does this happen, what have I done wrong? Here's my code:

```
template<typename T>
struct _range {
    T a;
    T b;

    _range(T a, T b):
        a(a),
        b(b)
    {
    }

    struct iterator {
        T it;

        iterator(T it):
            it(it)
        {
        }

        bool operator!=(const iterator &other) const
        {
            return it != other.it;
        }

        void operator++()
        {
            ++it;
        }

        T operator*() const
        {
            return it;
        }
    };

    iterator begin() const
    {
        return iterator(a);
    }

    iterator end() const
    {
        return iterator(b);
    }
};

template<typename T>
_range<T> range(const T a, const T b)
{
    return _range<T>(a, b);
}

template<typename F, typename T>
struct _map {
    const F &f;
    const T &t;

    _map(const F &f, const T &t):
        f(f),
        t(t)
    {
    }

    struct iterator {
        const F &f;
        typename T::iterator it;

        iterator(const F &f, typename T::iterator it):
            f(f),
            it(it)
        {
        }

        bool operator!=(const iterator &other) const
        {
            return it != other.it;
        }

        void operator++()
        {
            ++it;
        }

        int operator*() const
        {
            return f(*it);
        }
    };

    iterator begin() const
    {
        return iterator(f, t.begin());
    }

    iterator end() const
    {
        return iterator(f, t.end());
    }
};

template<typename F, typename T>
_map<F, T> map(const F &f, const T &t)
{
    return _map<F, T>(f, t);
}

#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdio>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for (int i: map([] (int x) { return 3 * x; }, range(-4, 5)))
        printf("%d\n", i);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe a bug? With Clang++, it works fine with both at the O1 and O2 optimization levels.

Comment: Try having `_map` store its members by value rather than storing const refs. (I suspect your `range` object is being destroyed earlier than you had hoped.)

Comment: i believe @ildjarn got it right: the temporary is forced to live as long as the constant reference it is bound to is alive. the reference it is bound to is the argument of `map`'s constructor. when the constructor returns, the reference goes out of scope and the temporary gets destroyed.

Comment: Yes, very nice, thanks! Please create an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<sub>Summarizing the existing comments:</sub>

`range(-4, 5)` creates a temporary, and (in most cases) temporaries only live until the end of the full-expression in which they are created. So in your case, the returned `_range` object is valid during the construction of the `_map`, but as soon as said `_map` is returned from `map`, the full-expression ends and the `_range` object is destroyed.

That said, because `_map` holds the arguments passed to its constructor by const ref rather than by value, this means that by the time the range-based `for` begins executing, your `_map::t` is already a dangling reference – classic [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

To fix this, simply have `_map` store its data members by value.